# .Net 2.0 HttpUtility.UrlEncode issue

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with a project in .Net 2.0, this must stay in .Net 2.0 I have no way around this as this is what the customer wants.

I am trying to create a string that is going to url encode this

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key);`

However, I get the message

> HttpUtility does not contain a definition for UrlEncode

Looking at MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.80).aspx I see that this should be easily possible.

I have my using statement bringing in System.Web and it is in my references too.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Comment: What is the type of `key`?

Comment: Just tried with a console app in .NET 2.0. Works perfectly with `UrlEncode(string str)`. Have you other class with the same name HttpUtility? Are you certain of compiling with .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek its of type of string

Comment: @Ksv3n I dont believe that there is another class with the same name, but the project we have inherited is old and there are no standards within it

Comment: @Ksv3n my apologies for the the late(r) response. Ive been I'll, however there is no other reference to HttpUtility, and even using the fully qualified reference so i just dont understand why this isnt working.

Answer (score -3):

If you are having trouble with system.web use the alternate method as shown in this blog. [Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Feb/05/Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb)

Comment: Question clearly says _"System.Web is in my references"_